# okhttp client truncates http URL at # sign

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp

I am using okhttp client (version 3.10.0) to call Bing service. The Address used in the test has # sign.

1177 PARK AVE STE 5 #190
ORANGE PARK
FL 320734150
US

http client truncates the address component at # sign. URL constructed through the code is

**https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/1177%20PARK%20AVE%20STE%205?%20maxresults=1&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&o=xml**

Code fragment is shown below

```
Request.Builder builder = bingOkHttpClient.newRequestBuilder(path, buildQueryParams());
builder.addHeader("Accept","application/xml");
bingOkHttpClient.newCall(builder.build()).execute();
```

If i replace # with the word suite, then url contructed is correctly

**https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Location1s/177%20PARK%20AVE%20STE%205%20suite#20190%ORANGE%20PARK%20FL%320734150%US?maxresults=1&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&o=xml**

Is there any other way to make the url constructed with # without getting truncated?

Comment: As `#` is used to refer to elements on an HTML page and no browser sends that to the server but rather processes it locally, I believe you'd have to URL encode the whole path yourself. As a quick fix, you could try replacing `#` with `%23`, which is its representation in URL encoding. No idea whether that'll work, however; okhttp might encode the `%` on its own, which would then break the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some symbols (including '#') are not valid URL symbols. If your URL needs to include them they need to be encoded. So take your original URL string and encode it with method `URLEncoder.encode(...)` Here is Javadoc for [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Comment: Can you confirm that okhttp does not encode the URL anyway? (Without other modifications to OP's code, that is.) That'd break the whole URL...

Comment: I believe okhttp (or any other http client) does not encode URL. I can not guarantee it, but you can easily test it. Encode your URL and see that it works. If it does then your encoding made a difference and that means that okhttp did not encode it on its own. In any case URL with symbols like # and other invalid symbols is considered strictly speaking illegal URL. So, you really should encode it anyway. It is already partially encoded as you used %20 instead of spaces

Comment: Yes, this helped. There is coding logic in place to replace space with %20. I removed that code block and used URLEncoder.encode(...) method. It worked. I see good response from Bing Service. # is a valid character in US postal addressline as per usps.com. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I confirm okHttp client doesn't encode URL.