# Why and how spring rest controller special characters(\n, \r) in String request are ignored?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-rest

I am having class like below :

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test/{code}")
    public String getTest(
        @PathVariable("code") final String code,
        @RequestParam("input") final String input) {

        log.info("path variable: {}", code);
        log.info("query param: {}", input);

        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    @PostMapping("/entryTest")
    public String entryPostCall(@RequestBody final TestData test) {
        log.info("test data: {}", test.getValue());
        
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

TestData class :

```
public class TestData {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

If I try with special chars(\n, \r) in queryParam and pathParam, like below.

```
http://localhost:8080/test/dumm\ny?input=data\ntest
```

It's throwing `HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request`

But if I try with entryPostCall method(@PostMapping with @RequestBody), it's sanitized the input and received input without \n or \r.
How it's working?

Answer (score 0):

Some symbols in URL are invalid. \n and \r are among them. pass them in URL they need to be encoded. See this question that shows how to do it:
[okhttp client truncates http URL at # sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67861705/okhttp-client-truncates-http-url-at-sign/67861937#67861937)

Comment: entryPostCall is a POST method, you are not passing your params through URL, so this is why you didn't get an ERROR. as to why it ignored your symbols it has to do with how its parsed your input into a class TestData. Spring boot uses Jackson JSON to parse the input into a class. This is a different issue though.